# How do I use "this" as a part of a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to do it this:

```
$(this + ' li:not(:nth-last-child(2)):not(:last-child)').hide()
```

Full code sample:

```
$('.comments').each(function(){
    $(this + ' li:not(:nth-last-child(2)):not(:last-child)').hide()
    var template = $('#expand').html();
    $(this).prepend(template)
});
```

I need to run it as an "each"-function because I want to put in a conditional later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try *this*:

```
$('li:not(:nth-last-child(2)):not(:last-child)', this).hide();
```

From [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

> jQuery( selector [, context] )
>
> selector - A string containing a selector expression
>
> context - A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

So you can use `this` as context parameter:

```
$('.comments').each(function(){
    $('li:not(:nth-last-child(2)):not(:last-child)', this).hide()
    var template = $('#expand').html();
    $(this).prepend(template)
});
```

Comment: Worth noting that behind the scenes, all `$(selector, context)` does is call `$(context).find(selector)`: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.init

Comment: Yeah, `$(selector, context)` is calling `$(context).find(selector)`, but **it works**. I don't understand what you meant by "Worth noting"...?

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to find all the `li:not(:nth-last-child(2)):not(:last-child)` within `this`, you could use `find()`:

```
$(this).find('li:not(:nth-last-child(2)):not(:last-child)').hide();
```

Also worth noting if you know the elements you're looking for are only going to be one level deep, then you should use `children()` instead of `find()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an object not a string to which you can attach other strings in order to build the selector you need.

Just use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to traverse the code:

```
$('.comments').each(function(){
    $(this).find('li').not(':nth-last-child(2)').not(':last-child').hide();
    var template = $('#expand').html();
    $(this).prepend(template);
});
```